# Setup Spring MVC app with Intellij + tomcat

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have a spring MVC app that come from `Eclipse` (No spring boot app) and I am trying to configure it to run inside an embedded `Tomcat` container from  `Intellij` IDE.

I downloaded the `smart Tomcat` plugin for `Intellij` and I configured it (at least I  tried) but when I tried to run the server it returns the error **"The Module Root Specified is not a module according to Intellij"**. I solved this problem crating and adding the artefact to the build

Once I solved this problem the server start and now tomcat is returning this type of warnings:

```
Mar 09, 2020 1:29:45 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'Server/Service/Engine/Host/web-app/display-name'.
Mar 09, 2020 1:29:45 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'Server/Service/Engine/Host/web-app/servlet/servlet-name'.
Mar 09, 2020 1:29:45 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'Server/Service/Engine/Host/web-app/servlet/servlet-class'.
Mar 09, 2020 1:29:45 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'Server/Service/Engine/Host/web-app/servlet/init-param/param-name'.
....
```

Any idea how to fix this problem and what does this exactly mean? I am completely lost.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the not just warnings? Were you getting the same warnings when using `Eclipse` with similar setup? How is the warning even related to `IntelliJ`?

Comment: I have apparently found the first stone. From eclipse it is loading CATALINA_HOME and CATALINA_BASE from the correct path C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\... but the configuration from intellij is accessing to C:\Users\My system user\.SmartTomcat\ ...

In the SmartTomcat plugin I selected the right path so I don't understand why Tomcat form intellij is going to my user profile directory instead of the right one?